# NumberFormatting exception for bigint

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am using database as postgresql, connecting to the database with spring jdbctemplate.

The phone column in database is `phone bigint` The spring is throwing the `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

```java
            public UserDetails getUserDetails(int phone) {
    
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM users where phone = ?";
            UserDetails users = (UserDetails) jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new Object[]{phone},
                    new BeanPropertyRowMapper<UserDetails>(UserDetails.class));
            return users;
            }

**Error:-**

> For input string: "7894561230"; nested exception is
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7894561230"
```

My Bean is :-

```java
    public class UserDetails {
        
        private int userId;
        private String name;
        private String email;
        private String phone;
    }
```

Comment: Why is `phone` a `String` in your Java class, but a `bigint` in the database? Those two types should match (it should be `text` in the database)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name after changing the phone from String to int I am getting  Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "7894561230"]

Comment: it is saying for input String but I am giving int as input as shown in the method

Comment: @Gen `7894561230` value will be out of range for int. try it with `long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is with `int`.

In Java `int` can hold any whole number from `-2147483648` to `2147483647` and your value `7894561230` is out of range for it. So use `long` in place of `int`.